# Charging Lithium Ion batteries 18650

Tags: lithium-ion

I connected 10x Lithium Ion batteries in series (3.7V, 2100mAh), I looked into the datasheet and the charging voltage is 4.2V with a current of 1A.

Can I simply solder this [battery management system](https://www.ebay.de/itm/164471998012?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=707-134425-41852-0&mkcid=2&itemid=164471998012&targetid=857931346246&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9043138&poi=&campaignid=10215338140&mkgroupid=105782587127&rlsatarget=pla-857931346246&abcId=1139676&merchantid=138405830&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsZCjkvml8AIVR-h3Ch2WJQJuEAQYAiABEgJtgfD_BwE) to the battery string and connect it to a 42V 2A charger to safely charge it or will it blow up?

Comment: Somebody stop this man before he does it

Comment: Oh no. Do NOT ever do such a thing. It might explode randomly. In short, the single weakest cell will charge faster than others, exceeding the 4.2V first, get hot, boom.
Search for a balancer circuit, or Li-ion charging problematic in general. It's found almost everywhere around the web.

Comment: THank you guys I found it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally when dealing with lithium based batteries you need to be extra careful and you have to know exactly what are you doing, because there is a great risk of **fire** or **explosion** when you handle them unproperly (overcharging, short circuit, overtemperature etc.).

If you want to charge multiple cells in series, you should always use balancing circuit that takes care of charging all cells to the exactly same voltage. When you do not use a balancer, the cells will eventually get charged to different voltages after few cycles. The difference in voltages between each cell will get bigger over time and if you are lucky, you will only end up with a dead cell in a battery pack; if you are unlucky, it may catch fire.

Also, discharging an unbalanced pack will lower it's overall capacity and may even lead to  negative voltage on some of the cells.

> I looked into the datasheet and the charging voltage is 4.2V with a current of 1A.

> connect it to a 42V 2A charger

It is OK to charge the cells with lower current than their maximum rating, but you should never exceed the maximum charging current, that they are specified at. (Charging them with lower currents will actually prolong their life)

There are many [articles on battery balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battery_balancing) on the internet, you should go through them first.